# Django South Migration for newly cloned project

Tags: django, django-south, database-migration

I cloned the Django project from my friend git account.The project has lot of Apps include south and all the apps have migration files.After cloning,i created database and run syncdb to create south table, then only we can migrate schema for other apps.But i ended with error like
some relations not exists.
What is the correct procedure to start with django south.
Note: The project has auth app with inherits abstract user module in django 1.5
Help me to solve.Adavance thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As migrations already exists, use fake migrations, just to "record the migration sequence as having been applied, but not actually run it".

```
./manage.py migrate myapp --fake
```

For details: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html